# Why this Unions are required in between Structure while developing USB peripheral driver?

Tags: c, embedded, driver, cmsis

```
/* ================================================================================ */
/* ================                      USB0                      ================ */
/* ================================================================================ */


/**
  * @brief Register map for USB0 peripheral (USB0)
  */

typedef struct {                                    /*!< USB0 Structure                                                        */
  __IO uint8_t   FADDR;                             /*!< USB Device Functional Address                                         */
  __IO uint8_t   POWER;                             /*!< USB Power                                                             */
  __IO uint16_t  TXIS;                              /*!< USB Transmit Interrupt Status                                         */
  __IO uint16_t  RXIS;                              /*!< USB Receive Interrupt Status                                          */
  __IO uint16_t  TXIE;                              /*!< USB Transmit Interrupt Enable                                         */
  __IO uint16_t  RXIE;                              /*!< USB Receive Interrupt Enable                                          */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   IS_USB0_ALT;                     /*!< USB General Interrupt Status                                          */
    __IO uint8_t   IS;                              /*!< USB General Interrupt Status                                          */
  };

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   IE_USB0_ALT;                     /*!< USB Interrupt Enable                                                  */
    __IO uint8_t   IE;                              /*!< USB Interrupt Enable                                                  */
  };
  __IO uint16_t  FRAME;                             /*!< USB Frame Value                                                       */
  __IO uint8_t   EPIDX;                             /*!< USB Endpoint Index                                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   TEST;                              /*!< USB Test Mode                                                         */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED[4];
  __IO uint32_t  FIFO0;                             /*!< USB FIFO Endpoint 0                                                   */
  __IO uint32_t  FIFO1;                             /*!< USB FIFO Endpoint 1                                                   */
  __IO uint32_t  FIFO2;                             /*!< USB FIFO Endpoint 2                                                   */
  __IO uint32_t  FIFO3;                             /*!< USB FIFO Endpoint 3                                                   */
  __IO uint32_t  FIFO4;                             /*!< USB FIFO Endpoint 4                                                   */
  __IO uint32_t  FIFO5;                             /*!< USB FIFO Endpoint 5                                                   */
  __IO uint32_t  FIFO6;                             /*!< USB FIFO Endpoint 6                                                   */
  __IO uint32_t  FIFO7;                             /*!< USB FIFO Endpoint 7                                                   */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED1[8];
  __IO uint8_t   DEVCTL;                            /*!< USB Device Control                                                    */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED2;
  __IO uint8_t   TXFIFOSZ;                          /*!< USB Transmit Dynamic FIFO Sizing                                      */
  __IO uint8_t   RXFIFOSZ;                          /*!< USB Receive Dynamic FIFO Sizing                                       */
  __IO uint16_t  TXFIFOADD;                         /*!< USB Transmit FIFO Start Address                                       */
  __IO uint16_t  RXFIFOADD;                         /*!< USB Receive FIFO Start Address                                        */
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED3[9];
  __IO uint8_t   CONTIM;                            /*!< USB Connect Timing                                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   VPLEN;                             /*!< USB OTG VBUS Pulse Timing                                             */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED4;
  __IO uint8_t   FSEOF;                             /*!< USB Full-Speed Last Transaction to End of Frame Timing                */
  __IO uint8_t   LSEOF;                             /*!< USB Low-Speed Last Transaction to End of Frame Timing                 */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED5;
  __IO uint8_t   TXFUNCADDR0;                       /*!< USB Transmit Functional Address Endpoint 0                            */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED6;
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBADDR0;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Address Endpoint 0                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBPORT0;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Port Endpoint 0                                      */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED7;
  __IO uint8_t   TXFUNCADDR1;                       /*!< USB Transmit Functional Address Endpoint 1                            */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED8;
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBADDR1;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Address Endpoint 1                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBPORT1;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Port Endpoint 1                                      */
  __IO uint8_t   RXFUNCADDR1;                       /*!< USB Receive Functional Address Endpoint 1                             */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED9;
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBADDR1;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Address Endpoint 1                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBPORT1;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Port Endpoint 1                                       */
  __IO uint8_t   TXFUNCADDR2;                       /*!< USB Transmit Functional Address Endpoint 2                            */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED10;
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBADDR2;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Address Endpoint 2                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBPORT2;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Port Endpoint 2                                      */
  __IO uint8_t   RXFUNCADDR2;                       /*!< USB Receive Functional Address Endpoint 2                             */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED11;
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBADDR2;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Address Endpoint 2                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBPORT2;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Port Endpoint 2                                       */
  __IO uint8_t   TXFUNCADDR3;                       /*!< USB Transmit Functional Address Endpoint 3                            */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED12;
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBADDR3;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Address Endpoint 3                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBPORT3;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Port Endpoint 3                                      */
  __IO uint8_t   RXFUNCADDR3;                       /*!< USB Receive Functional Address Endpoint 3                             */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED13;
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBADDR3;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Address Endpoint 3                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBPORT3;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Port Endpoint 3                                       */
  __IO uint8_t   TXFUNCADDR4;                       /*!< USB Transmit Functional Address Endpoint 4                            */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED14;
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBADDR4;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Address Endpoint 4                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBPORT4;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Port Endpoint 4                                      */
  __IO uint8_t   RXFUNCADDR4;                       /*!< USB Receive Functional Address Endpoint 4                             */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED15;
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBADDR4;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Address Endpoint 4                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBPORT4;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Port Endpoint 4                                       */
  __IO uint8_t   TXFUNCADDR5;                       /*!< USB Transmit Functional Address Endpoint 5                            */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED16;
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBADDR5;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Address Endpoint 5                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBPORT5;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Port Endpoint 5                                      */
  __IO uint8_t   RXFUNCADDR5;                       /*!< USB Receive Functional Address Endpoint 5                             */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED17;
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBADDR5;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Address Endpoint 5                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBPORT5;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Port Endpoint 5                                       */
  __IO uint8_t   TXFUNCADDR6;                       /*!< USB Transmit Functional Address Endpoint 6                            */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED18;
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBADDR6;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Address Endpoint 6                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBPORT6;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Port Endpoint 6                                      */
  __IO uint8_t   RXFUNCADDR6;                       /*!< USB Receive Functional Address Endpoint 6                             */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED19;
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBADDR6;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Address Endpoint 6                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBPORT6;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Port Endpoint 6                                       */
  __IO uint8_t   TXFUNCADDR7;                       /*!< USB Transmit Functional Address Endpoint 7                            */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED20;
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBADDR7;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Address Endpoint 7                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   TXHUBPORT7;                        /*!< USB Transmit Hub Port Endpoint 7                                      */
  __IO uint8_t   RXFUNCADDR7;                       /*!< USB Receive Functional Address Endpoint 7                             */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED21;
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBADDR7;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Address Endpoint 7                                    */
  __IO uint8_t   RXHUBPORT7;                        /*!< USB Receive Hub Port Endpoint 7                                       */
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED22[33];

  union {
    __O  uint8_t   CSRL0_USB0_ALT;                  /*!< USB Control and Status Endpoint 0 Low                                 */
    __O  uint8_t   CSRL0;                           /*!< USB Control and Status Endpoint 0 Low                                 */
  };
  __O  uint8_t   CSRH0;                             /*!< USB Control and Status Endpoint 0 High                                */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED23;
  __IO uint8_t   COUNT0;                            /*!< USB Receive Byte Count Endpoint 0                                     */
  __I  uint8_t   RESERVED24;
  __IO uint8_t   TYPE0;                             /*!< USB Type Endpoint 0                                                   */
  __IO uint8_t   NAKLMT;                            /*!< USB NAK Limit                                                         */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED25;
  __IO uint16_t  TXMAXP1;                           /*!< USB Maximum Transmit Data Endpoint 1                                  */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL1_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 1 Low                        */
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL1;                         /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 1 Low                        */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   TXCSRH1;                           /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 1 High                       */
  __IO uint16_t  RXMAXP1;                           /*!< USB Maximum Receive Data Endpoint 1                                   */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL1_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 1 Low                         */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL1;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 1 Low                         */
  };

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH1_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 1 High                        */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH1;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 1 High                        */
  };
  __IO uint16_t  RXCOUNT1;                          /*!< USB Receive Byte Count Endpoint 1                                     */
  __IO uint8_t   TXTYPE1;                           /*!< USB Host Transmit Configure Type Endpoint 1                           */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL1_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 1                                 */
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL1;                     /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 1                                 */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   RXTYPE1;                           /*!< USB Host Configure Receive Type Endpoint 1                            */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL1_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 1                          */
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL1;                     /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 1                          */
  };
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED26;
  __IO uint16_t  TXMAXP2;                           /*!< USB Maximum Transmit Data Endpoint 2                                  */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL2_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 2 Low                        */
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL2;                         /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 2 Low                        */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   TXCSRH2;                           /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 2 High                       */
  __IO uint16_t  RXMAXP2;                           /*!< USB Maximum Receive Data Endpoint 2                                   */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL2_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 2 Low                         */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL2;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 2 Low                         */
  };

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH2_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 2 High                        */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH2;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 2 High                        */
  };
  __IO uint16_t  RXCOUNT2;                          /*!< USB Receive Byte Count Endpoint 2                                     */
  __IO uint8_t   TXTYPE2;                           /*!< USB Host Transmit Configure Type Endpoint 2                           */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL2_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 2                                 */
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL2;                     /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 2                                 */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   RXTYPE2;                           /*!< USB Host Configure Receive Type Endpoint 2                            */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL2_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 2                          */
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL2;                     /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 2                          */
  };
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED27;
  __IO uint16_t  TXMAXP3;                           /*!< USB Maximum Transmit Data Endpoint 3                                  */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL3_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 3 Low                        */
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL3;                         /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 3 Low                        */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   TXCSRH3;                           /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 3 High                       */
  __IO uint16_t  RXMAXP3;                           /*!< USB Maximum Receive Data Endpoint 3                                   */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL3_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 3 Low                         */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL3;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 3 Low                         */
  };

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH3_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 3 High                        */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH3;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 3 High                        */
  };
  __IO uint16_t  RXCOUNT3;                          /*!< USB Receive Byte Count Endpoint 3                                     */
  __IO uint8_t   TXTYPE3;                           /*!< USB Host Transmit Configure Type Endpoint 3                           */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL3_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 3                                 */
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL3;                     /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 3                                 */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   RXTYPE3;                           /*!< USB Host Configure Receive Type Endpoint 3                            */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL3_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 3                          */
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL3;                     /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 3                          */
  };
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED28;
  __IO uint16_t  TXMAXP4;                           /*!< USB Maximum Transmit Data Endpoint 4                                  */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL4_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 4 Low                        */
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL4;                         /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 4 Low                        */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   TXCSRH4;                           /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 4 High                       */
  __IO uint16_t  RXMAXP4;                           /*!< USB Maximum Receive Data Endpoint 4                                   */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL4_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 4 Low                         */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL4;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 4 Low                         */
  };

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH4_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 4 High                        */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH4;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 4 High                        */
  };
  __IO uint16_t  RXCOUNT4;                          /*!< USB Receive Byte Count Endpoint 4                                     */
  __IO uint8_t   TXTYPE4;                           /*!< USB Host Transmit Configure Type Endpoint 4                           */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL4_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 4                                 */
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL4;                     /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 4                                 */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   RXTYPE4;                           /*!< USB Host Configure Receive Type Endpoint 4                            */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL4_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 4                          */
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL4;                     /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 4                          */
  };
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED29;
  __IO uint16_t  TXMAXP5;                           /*!< USB Maximum Transmit Data Endpoint 5                                  */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL5_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 5 Low                        */
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL5;                         /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 5 Low                        */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   TXCSRH5;                           /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 5 High                       */
  __IO uint16_t  RXMAXP5;                           /*!< USB Maximum Receive Data Endpoint 5                                   */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL5_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 5 Low                         */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL5;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 5 Low                         */
  };

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH5_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 5 High                        */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH5;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 5 High                        */
  };
  __IO uint16_t  RXCOUNT5;                          /*!< USB Receive Byte Count Endpoint 5                                     */
  __IO uint8_t   TXTYPE5;                           /*!< USB Host Transmit Configure Type Endpoint 5                           */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL5_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 5                                 */
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL5;                     /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 5                                 */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   RXTYPE5;                           /*!< USB Host Configure Receive Type Endpoint 5                            */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL5_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 5                          */
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL5;                     /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 5                          */
  };
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED30;
  __IO uint16_t  TXMAXP6;                           /*!< USB Maximum Transmit Data Endpoint 6                                  */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL6_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 6 Low                        */
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL6;                         /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 6 Low                        */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   TXCSRH6;                           /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 6 High                       */
  __IO uint16_t  RXMAXP6;                           /*!< USB Maximum Receive Data Endpoint 6                                   */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL6_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 6 Low                         */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL6;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 6 Low                         */
  };

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH6_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 6 High                        */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH6;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 6 High                        */
  };
  __IO uint16_t  RXCOUNT6;                          /*!< USB Receive Byte Count Endpoint 6                                     */
  __IO uint8_t   TXTYPE6;                           /*!< USB Host Transmit Configure Type Endpoint 6                           */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL6_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 6                                 */
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL6;                     /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 6                                 */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   RXTYPE6;                           /*!< USB Host Configure Receive Type Endpoint 6                            */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL6_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 6                          */
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL6;                     /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 6                          */
  };
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED31;
  __IO uint16_t  TXMAXP7;                           /*!< USB Maximum Transmit Data Endpoint 7                                  */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL7_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 7 Low                        */
    __IO uint8_t   TXCSRL7;                         /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 7 Low                        */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   TXCSRH7;                           /*!< USB Transmit Control and Status Endpoint 7 High                       */
  __IO uint16_t  RXMAXP7;                           /*!< USB Maximum Receive Data Endpoint 7                                   */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL7_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 7 Low                         */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRL7;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 7 Low                         */
  };

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH7_USB0_ALT;                /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 7 High                        */
    __IO uint8_t   RXCSRH7;                         /*!< USB Receive Control and Status Endpoint 7 High                        */
  };
  __IO uint16_t  RXCOUNT7;                          /*!< USB Receive Byte Count Endpoint 7                                     */
  __IO uint8_t   TXTYPE7;                           /*!< USB Host Transmit Configure Type Endpoint 7                           */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL7_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 7                                 */
    __IO uint8_t   TXINTERVAL7;                     /*!< USB Host Transmit Interval Endpoint 7                                 */
  };
  __IO uint8_t   RXTYPE7;                           /*!< USB Host Configure Receive Type Endpoint 7                            */

  union {
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL7_USB0_ALT;            /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 7                          */
    __IO uint8_t   RXINTERVAL7;                     /*!< USB Host Receive Polling Interval Endpoint 7                          */
  };
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED32[195];
  __IO uint16_t  RQPKTCOUNT1;                       /*!< USB Request Packet Count in Block Transfer Endpoint 1                 */
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED33;
  __IO uint16_t  RQPKTCOUNT2;                       /*!< USB Request Packet Count in Block Transfer Endpoint 2                 */
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED34;
  __IO uint16_t  RQPKTCOUNT3;                       /*!< USB Request Packet Count in Block Transfer Endpoint 3                 */
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED35;
  __IO uint16_t  RQPKTCOUNT4;                       /*!< USB Request Packet Count in Block Transfer Endpoint 4                 */
  __I  uint16_t  RESERVED36;
  __IO uint16_t  RQPKTCOUNT5;                       /*!< USB Request Packet 
} USB0_Type;
```

In this Driver why in between the `union` datatype is used?  Why can't we put it normally in structure.  What is need of special consideration?

Comment: None of this is "required" it is a popular hack or shortcut used.  Dangerous, but unfortunately becoming the norm (both using structs and unions like this).  Will crash and burn for various if not all folks eventually.  Appears they must have used alternate names for things in various libraries, rather than settling on one name, they appear to be using unions to allow both names.  I would/do avoid this code like the plague.  And also use code like this in interviews to see if the candidates understand the risks/problems with it.

Comment: Please note that this code is likely non-standard. Anonymous unions weren't possible in C before C11, and embedded compilers are slow at adapting to C11.

Answer (score 3):

This struct is meant to be used to access the registers of a peripheral.
If your hardware has these registers mapped starting at memory address 0x12340000, you could declare a pointer like this:

```c
USB0_Type * const ptr = (USB0_Type *)0x12340000;
```

and then access the registers by accessing the structure members, like this:

```c
ptr->TXIE = 1;  // enable TX interrupt
```

As for the unions, all members of a union share the same address.
In this case, this means that accesses to any of the union members access the same register.

```c
union {
  __IO uint8_t   IS_USB0_ALT;                     /*!< USB General Interrupt Status                                          */
  __IO uint8_t   IS;                              /*!< USB General Interrupt Status                                          */
};
```

The members use the same type, and you can see by the comments that the meaning of the register is the same in both cases, so the only purpose of this union is to allow the same register to be accessed by two different names.
This was likely done for backwards compatibility; they decided to rename the register, and kept the old name for old code.

```c
if (ptr->IS & 1) ...           // old code
if (ptr->IS_USB0_ALT & 1) ...  // new code
                               // both work
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great difference between `struct` and `union` in C.

Members of a `struct` don't overlap.  Members of a `struct` are located sequentially in the memory.

Each member of the `union` begins at the *same* location in memory.  They are all stacked on top of each-other.  Sounds bizarre, doesn't it?  How can we make use of something like this?  For example, can be used to do a reinterpret cast.  A value is written into one union member as a 32-bit integer, but read from another union member as an array of 8-bit integers.

(Yes, an array can be a member of a union.  The *first* member of the array will begin at the same location in memory as the rest of the union members.  The members of the array will occupy sequential locations in memory.)